# Cloudflare Workers KV Promises not parallelized?

Tags: cloudflare-workers

Getting multiple keys from KV through Cloudflare workers does not seem to be a parallelised process. For example, latency of code snippet below increases linearly with the length of `keys` queried

```
const kvPromises = keys.map(key => MY_NAMESPACE.get(key, "text"));
let kvValues = await Promise.all(kvPromises);
```

Is there any way to parallelise these? I could not find anything in the documentation, and the Cloudflare Community forum seems unhelpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can do multiple KV requests in parallel, Workers in general are limited to six concurrent outgoing requests on behalf of one incoming request, and KV requests are included in this limit (in addition to `fetch()`, Cache API, etc.). Thus, after the sixth request, further requests will wait for a previous request to complete. At this time there's no way to increase this limit.